# Beam Template Dataflow Region not working

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I specify the region parameter into the template creation

```
                  <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>foobarbaz</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--runner=DataflowRunner</argument>
                            <argument>--region=europe-west1</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

the parameter is sent to the template file

```
"clientRequestId" : "blablabla",
  "environment" : {
    "dataset" : "bigquery.googleapis.com/cloud_dataflow",
    "sdkPipelineOptions" : {
      "options" : {
        ...
        "region" : "europe-west1",
        ...
      },
```

but my job is still executed in us-central1

I have to force --region=europe-west1 in my

```
gcloud dataflow job run
```

command for it to be executed in europe-west1.

Is it normal? Do you have the same problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: I would expect the region to be honored. Could you provide the job id so that I can check more?